# Reversing half the words in a list of lists randomly in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, random

I have a long list of lists **words_lists** that contains word tokens (also containing duplicates) for specific documents  and also a **sublist** containing a few of the words from words_list.

I am trying to reverse **EXACTLY HALF** of the occurances of the words in the sublist **RANDOMLY** in words_list (so not just the first half of words reversed etc), note that the **word_list** should keep the same order.

This is what I have so far:

```
words_list = [['test', 'hello'] ,['world', 'what', 'favourite'],['test',...]..]
sublist = ['test','world']

import random
out = [w[::-1] if w in sublist and random.choice([True, False]) else w
       for w in words_list]
```

It works reasonably well, but for accuracy I would prefer **EXACTLY** half of occurances to be reversed.

I have created a bit of code (seen below) that shuffles a list containing True or False of size **occurances** but I can't wrap my head around how I can use this in by original list comprehension loop, could anyone help

```
 
        decisions = []
        for i in range(occurrences):
            if i < occurrences/2:
                decisions.append(True)
            else:
                decisions.append(False)
        
        random.shuffle(decisions)
```

Comment: Since `words_list` is a list of lists, `w` is a list, not a word. How is `if w in sublist` finding any matches?

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the indexes of all the words in `word_list` that are in `sublist`. Use `random.sample()` to select half of those indexes randomly. Then reverse the elements of the original list with those indexes.

```
indexes = [i for i, w in enumerate(words_list) if w in sublist]
random_half = set(random.sample(indexes, len(indexes)//2))
out = [w[::-1] if i in random_half else w for i, w in enumerate(words_list)]
```